# Python Tkinter Not Responding when Computing, How to Solve?

Tags: python, tkinter

The tkinter code goes something like this:

```
def process():
    label1.configure(text="something")
    function1()
    label1.configure(text="else")
    calculative_function()
    ...

button = Button(..,command= process,...)
```

The functions that process() calls might require a little computation power, however, not much (the regular numpy, pandas). Whenever I click the button that calls process(), I am unable to drag the GUI Window, and when I try to, the window stops responding.

Moreover, the labels don't change before function calls. However, if I try to print something on the console before function calls, it's printed. That says that my functions are running, but the label updates are not taking place and the gui does not respond.
After the program completes executing, the gui shows the last updated label.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: It would be much helpful if you include your code.. bug could be in the code itself.. good luck.